# clojure: how to bind console input to a variable?

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I'm trying to learn clojure, but coming from OO background simple things look like mission impossible. For instance, how do I write the function that would accept console input and output it into console as well?

I'm trying something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
(ns ClojureTest2.core)

,(defn fun [] 
   (let [input (read-line)]) 
   (println input)
 )

(fun [])
```

P.S. I work with eclipse - counterclockwise

Comment: you probably don't want to hear this but...ditch eclipse. If you spend the time to learn emacs along with nrepl and paredit, your life will become infinitely more simple. I would suggest you start with emacs live until you're ready to build up your own config - https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(ns ClojureTest2.core)

(defn fun []
  (let [input (read-line)]
    (println input)))

(fun)
```

Note how the `println` is enclosed in the `let` statement. `input` will only exist within the `let` statement. Also, the empty parameter list of `fun` means you do not need to supply any arguments to call it.